# No co-prime neighbors

Tags: code-golf, array, restricted-source, decision-problem, primes

Given a list of positive integers, output whether every adjacent pair of integers in it shares a prime factor. In other words, output **truthy** if and only if **no** two neighboring integers in the list are co-prime.

In yet other terms: given a list of positive integers **[a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> … a<sub>n</sub>]**, output whether

**gcd(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) > 1 && gcd(a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>) > 1 && … && gcd(a<sub>n−1</sub>, a<sub>n</sub>) > 1.**

The list will always contain at least two elements (n ≥ 2).

### However…

This challenge is also [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source): the *codepoints* in your answer (whatever codepage it may be in) must satisfy the condition your program checks for.

For example, `print 2` is a valid program. As a list of Unicode codepoints it is **[112 114 105 110 116 32 50]**, which satisfies this condition: **112** and **114** share a factor of **2**; and **114** and **105** share a factor of **3**, etc.

However, `main` can *not* occur in a valid program (sorry!), as the Unicode codepoints of `m` and `a`, namely **109** and **97**, are coprime. (Thankfully, your submission needn’t be a full program!)

Your program isn’t allowed to contain codepoint 0.

### Test cases

Truthy:

```
[6 21] -> 1
[502 230 524 618 996] -> 1
[314 112 938 792 309] -> 1
[666 642 658 642 849 675 910 328 320] -> 1
[922 614 530 660 438 854 861 357 477] -> 1
```

Falsy:

```
[6 7] -> 0
[629 474 502 133 138] -> 0
[420 679 719 475 624] -> 0
[515 850 726 324 764 555 752 888 467] -> 0
[946 423 427 507 899 812 786 576 844] -> 0
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: For anyone attempting this challenge in a normal programming language, this is a list of characters that have prime codepoints in ASCII: `%)+/5;=CGIOSYaegkmq\DEL`.

Comment: @Lynn Do Truthys have to be consistent?

Comment: @H.PWiz Nope! —

Comment: I actually intended this to be doable for _some_ normal (non-golf) langs, and I was feeling hopeful when I noticed that `print 2` was valid, but `);=ae` being prime is really tough, I didn’t consider that… I wonder if something like Haskell can compete?

Comment: This restriction is easier than the reverse of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131873/i-dont-even-i-only-odd), assume no-one use 0x02 byte. That question get nongolf valid answer in Mathematica, Logo, Haskell, Python, Perl, TI-BASIC. This one already got a Haskell, I think Mathematica is impossible, but Logo looks very likely to be possible, although I've not yet done constructing the solution.

Comment: @user202729 In the end, the Logo solution turns out to be too tedious to write (similar to JSF), and certainly not very golfy.

Answer (score 15):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
!TM1*Zdl2$Xdl-
```

This outputs a non-empty column vector of nonzero numbers as truthy, or a vector containing at least a zero entry as falsy.

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XzHE11ArKiXHSCUiJUf3//9oSyMjBTNDEwVTYwMFMzMDBRNjCwULUxMFCzNDBWNTcwUTc/NYAA)
- [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XY/BasMwEETv/ooptAQKDdJqtZJOvfTaWw6lIdCA7Vqg2iF2KDn02911oGAqWAmt3syOvo5TmT/wtx5QD9vt9rvLpZnvdq/28b0udP9Wl6f5eUXlttpM58vUXTfL9XQZO4zTOfef1c8Ka8rYVJv2WMaF@wce1mBfVy/rFHk8leO12q16N60ObdAOZ@S@zX2eGpRhOM17AdlDtfeGQM7AE0NsREqiXWcZ1hKSiwiJ4EzSrohAmCA@3s7ICRI8kjVwFLWMUomUUL1XVxEDVo/oGVEsnA/gEBYv3HZKeldWU1jntKJ2mVQZEoJdXj2EeElqvfoYBBKdxAiiOu8RvCaJESyLY2IBk9MK6hoQU0LUn4Qo8EE0Mx/wCw). The footer code contains an `if` branch to test truthyness/falsyness.
- Since MATL uses ASCII, the source code is encoded as

  ```
  [33 84 77 49 42 90 100 108 50 36 88 100 108 45]
  ```

  which [satisfies the requirement](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/XzHE11ArKiXHSCUiJUf3//9oY2MFCxMFc3MFE0sFEyMFSwMFQwMQtlAwNVAwNlOwsIALmJjGAgA).

#### Explanation

```
!     % Implicit input. Transpose
TM    % Push input to latest function again
1*    % Multiply by 1 (does nothing, but matches factors)
Zd    % Compute gcd with broadcast: matrix of gcd of all pairs
l     % Push 1
2$    % The next function will use 2 inputs
Xd    % Extract diagonal 1 (i.e. that below the main diagonal) from the matrix
l-    % Subtract 1 from each entry. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Congratulations on an answer which *does* satisfy the [tag:restricted-source] requirement!

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>103</s> 100 bytes

EDIT:

- -3 bytes: Used a `d<-fz` guard to merge and shorten the last two lines.

`f` is the main function, which takes a list of integers and returns a `Bool`.

Note that the first two `ԁ`s (only) are Cyrillic (Komi) Unicode characters, and there's a tab character before the first one.

```hs
f	ԁ=zb[ԁ]id
zb[h:p:l]fz=z h p&&zb[p:l]fz
zb l fz=z 0 2
z 0z=z>z^0
z f fz|f<fz=z fz f|d<-fz=z d$f-d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU9tasJAFPxdT7EUEcVEsl9vd0W9iLUQmywJXVNRSyH4xzt6n3ReWgiT2Zn3Znab8vpZpzScyrbbtt2tvpQft@l3l9quvq5O5Xk@f0v57tp8/YgklkvxKvIdAIy1eRRpsVhd6rJarMadIb48H9v@uH8@Dm01AWnW53U6xH7bi0acZzNIfwJMZI5GIdQECLrr3wvQCP0eN6MZ8d2rTT4eqmnMq2HYUyaUPEz2tlBgusiEVSYTJH0mQiA4WuIsJeygIboAposAhwjbZHAm6/@ZNwHMWUxLhGnlGQpMB8WDHGa5hghgONFbaJ4kBq2D5hxno4l/KrDCS3xBqTWDh2MUhzjYTo4zqCRl@CnScihsp4jbse2IIywMZ/mWHr2GuCEYzBilGRzXAHxAoucnOw/XOuKHIfsX)
or [test it on itself.](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5uZV5JalJhcolKckV@ul6aXm1igkFaUn@uaV5r7P43zSqNtVVL0lcbYzBQuICPDqsAqJzatyrZKIUOhQE0NKAQRAEoq5CiAJQwUjLiAJJBpVxVnAGSmAcVr0mzAkmlAVJNiowvmpKik6ab8p4stAA)

## How it works

- `f` is the main function. All it does is wrap its argument `ԁ` in a singleton list (because the prime ASCII value of `)` makes parentheses much more awkward to use than square brackets) and call `zb` with that and a dummy argument (the Haskell function `id` happens to have just the right characters to fit here).

  - Getting the same character to fit besides both of `=]` is impossible with plain ASCII, so the argument is named with the 2-byte Unicode character `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KOMI DE (ԁ)`, codepoint value `3*7*61=U+0501`, which fits with all of those and `[`.

    - Since the codepoint is not even (the smallest option that is a legal identifier and also even uses three bytes), this required using a tab character instead of a space before it.
    - A seven bytes longer plain ASCII option is to rename the argument: `f fz|bf<-fz=zb[bf]fz`.
- `zb` takes two arguments, a singleton list whose element is the real list of numbers being recursed on, and a dummy argument `fz` needed only to get a `z` before the function's `=`s.

  - When the inner list has at least two elements, the function `z` is called with the first two (named `h` and `p`), and if that returns `True`, `zb` recurses on the tail `p:l` of the list.
  - If the inner list has fewer than two elements, `zb` returns `True`. Since `=` needs to be followed by the character `z`, the simplest way to do this is to use a call of the `z` function that itself is known to return `True`.
- `z` takes two arguments and recursively calculates their greatest common divisor using subtraction (every other relevant integer division or gcd function is unavailable), returning `True` if it's greater than one.

  - The recursion ends when the first argument is `0`, with the second argument being the gcd. On this line the second argument is also named `z`. The character `1` is awkward here so `z^0` is used to get the number one.
  - Otherwise, if the first argument `f` is smaller than the second `fz`, they are swapped and `z` recurses.
  - Otherwise, the smaller argument is subtracted from the larger, then `z` recurses (also swapping the arguments, although that's just to avoid parentheses.)

Comment: I *knew* there had to be some non-golf language that could pull it off!

Comment: @Lynn It really helps Haskell in this kind of challenge that it has a fairly expressive syntactic subset with just single-character tokens. Which is about halfway to a golfing language, I guess.

Comment: Because of the Cyrillic, is this really 100 bytes? The [Code Golf Graduation userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/graduation-design-ideas/7955#7955) reports 102 UTF-8 bytes, but I don't know if it's accurate/that's the right way to count the bytes here. No matter how many bytes, it's really impressive!

Comment: @MarkS. TIO reports 100 bytes (and 98 chars). I suspect you got caught out by the tab character, which SE displays as 3 spaces (which then gets copied as such). I think I've seen someone use pre tags to avoid that, let me try to fix it.

Comment: @MarkS. Done. Although I suspect that might just confuse that userscript even more.

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

For Truthy inputs it returns a positive integer, for Falsy it returns 0

```
←▼`Ṡt(ż⌋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9odXNr///ihpDilrxg4bmgdCjFvOKMi////1s1MTUsODUwLDcyNiwzMjQsNzY0LDU1NSw3NTIsODg4LDQ2N10) and [Tested on its own codepoints](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9odXNr///ihpDilrxg4bmgdCjFvOKMi////1s2LDE4OSw5NiwyMDgsMTE2LDQwLDIzNSwxNDFd)

Uses Husk's [codepage](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
Source -- [ ←  , ▼  , `  , Ṡ  , t  , (  , ż  , ⌋  ]
Hex    -- [0x06,0xbd,0x60,0xd0,0x74,0x28,0xeb,0x8d]
Dec    -- [6   ,189 ,96  ,208 ,116 ,40  ,235 ,141]
```

#### Explanation

```
          -- implicit input, e.g                                  [63,36,18,3]
  `       -- flip the args of the next function
   Ṡ      -- some combinator (Ṡ f g x = f (g x) x)
    t     -- tail                                                 [36,18,3]
      ż   -- zipWith (note, keeps trailing elems of longer list)  [(63,36),(36,18),(18,3),(3)]
       ⌋  -- gcd                                                  [9,9,3,3]
     (    -- used just to match restricted source criteria
 ▼        -- minimum of the list                                    3
←         -- minus 1                                                2
```

Comment: What is the notation called you use in the explanation for `Ṡ`? I see it on the docs too in the "type" column on the commands page and can't get my head around it so want to look it up so I might be able to learn it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's the definition of the function `Ṡ` in Haskell's syntax. It translates roughly to `Ṡ(f,g,x) = f(g(x),x)` in more mainstream languages.

Comment: [source link](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/blob/d44d87ff2b5fd62b6b699ea0b67a5b8857b33866/defs.hs#L515)

Comment: Although, when flipped, it becomes `\`Ṡ g f x = Ṡ f g x = f (g x) x`

Comment: Right, so I'd need to learn Haskell. The `x` you refer to above is the input then? ...and it is on the left of the `Ṡ`?

Comment: The x is the input, It is on the right of `Ṡ`, its third argument

Comment: I'm confused, the third (ignoring the parenthesis) is the gcd atom, no?

Comment: No, the first is `t`, the second is `ż⌋`. The second is not `ż` because the second arg of `\`Ṡ` must have the type `(x -> y -> z)`

Comment: @JonathanAllan If you join the [Husk chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53097/husk), we can try to explain it better there.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

#### Code

```
ü‚ÒüÃP≠P
```

Uses the [**05AB1E** encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md), which gives us the following list of code points:

```
hex: [0xFC, 0x82, 0xD2, 0xFC, 0xC3, 0x50, 0x16, 0x50]
dec: [252,  130,  210,  252,  195,  80,   22,   80]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8J5HDbMOTzq853BzwKPOBQH//0ebmZnpKJiZGAEJUwsoy8LEEsgyN9VRsDQ00FEwNrIAEQaxAA) or [Verify the source code!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8J5HDbMOTzq853BzwKPOBQH//0cbVLg56ygYVFgYgUgXMAkRcTYGkaYGINLQDMKOBQA)

#### Explanation

Since the gcd operator (`¿`) has a prime code point I had to look for other ways to check coprimality:

```
ü‚          # Get an array of adjacent pairs of the input
  Ò         # Factorize both elements of each pair in the array
   üÃ       # For each pair, get the intersection of both prime factorization lists
     P      # Product of each intersection (this leaves 1 when there is no intersection)
      ≠     # Check for each element whether it does not equal 1
       P    # Product of the booleans
```

Comment: What code points does this have in 05AB1E's code page? Can you add them into the answer?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder added

Comment: Any reason for `Ò` over `f`?

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
äj d¹¥Z
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5GogZLmlWg==&input=WzIyOCwxMDYsMzIsMTAwLDE4NSwxNjUsOTBd)

Code points:

```
Char    ä   j       d   ¹   ¥   Z
Hex    e4  6a  20  64  b9  a5  5a
Dec   228 106  32 100 185 165  90
```

#### Explanation

```
 äj d¹ ¥ Z
Uäj d) ==Z
             Implicit: U = input array, Z = 0
Uä           For each pair of items in the array:
  j            Return whether the two items are coprime.
    d)       Return true if any items are truthy, false otherwise.
       ==Z   Return whether this is equal to 0 (false -> true, true -> false).
             Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
,Pnælð2\P
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @[Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwhFgIxDAU9p8gBIppsk6a3WF8qMby@9Wsx3ASF4A69CRcJKeabmfn32xinO@7HfI354evu8/l9vN1bk8QIvCUE4YygZAi1ascLNCFBMAlWWBG2JRSNEQlQJEqz8LOWv58DWdhEMRyUUtBVrY@69NT7Dw)

Jelly has its own [code-page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) and the codepoints of each character are

```
Chr Hex Dec
,   2c   44
P   50   80
n   6e  110
æ   16   22
l   6c  108
ð   18   24
2   32   50
\   5c   92
P   50   80
```

This tests for non-coprime numbers by checking if `lcm(a, b) != a*b`. There might be a shorter solution as I just filtered for characters with even codepoints.

### Explanation

```
,Pnælð2\P  Input: array A
      2\   For each overlapping sublist of size 2
     ð       Reduce it using this dyad
,              Pair
 P             Product
  n            Not equals, 1 if true else 0
   æl          LCM
        P  Product
```

Comment: Genius! This is incredible :O

Comment: `,` is even so you can do ``æln,P¥ð2\`` for two less. Edit: I dropped the trailing `P`, make that one less :p)

Comment: Oh yeah, swap the arguments even :)

Answer (score 5):

## TI-BASIC, 38 bytes

```
Input L1:ΔList(cumSum(L1:augment(Ans+V,V+{0:2>sum(AnsL1=lcm(Ans+V,V+L1
```

TI-BASIC is tokenized into one- or two-byte tokens, as listed [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).

The trickiest parts of this solution were:

1. The comma token is a prime number (43), forcing me to surround it with multiples of 43 (in this case the V token, which is 86).
2. The gcd( token is a large prime number (47881), which means it couldn't be used at all.

The tokens for this program come out to:

```
token     hex     dec
Input     0xDC    220
L1        0x5D00  23808
:         0x3E    62
ΔList(    0xBB2C  47916
cumSum(   0xBB29  47913
L1        0x5D00  23808
:         0x3E    62
augment(  0x14    20
Ans       0x72    114
+         0x70    112
V         0x56    86
,         0x2B    43
V         0x56    86
+         0x70    112
{         0x08    8
0         0x30    48
:         0x3E    62
2         0x32    50
>         0x6C    106
sum(      0xB6    182
Ans       0x72    114
L1        0x5D00  23808
=         0x6A    106
lcm(      0xBB08  47880
Ans       0x72    114
+         0x70    112
V         0x56    86
,         0x2B    43
V         0x56    86
+         0x70    112
L1        0x5D00  23808
```

## Explanation

```
Input L1:                   Prompt the user to input L1.

ΔList(cumSum(L1:            Take the differences of the prefix sum of L1,
                            which in effect removes the first element (result in Ans).

augment(Ans+V,V+{0:         Append a 0 to the end of Ans.
                            V defaults to 0, so adding it is a no-op.
                            Ans now holds L1 shifted to the left by one element,
                            with a 0 shifted in.

      AnsL1=lcm(Ans+V,V+L1  Take the least common multiple of each corresponding element
                            of Ans and L1, and check if each is equal to their product.
                            This returns a list of booleans, each 1 corresponding to
                            a co-prime pair. The last element (having been paired with 0)
                            will always be 1.

2>sum(                      Returns 1 if there is at most one 1 in the list, else 0.
                            Since the last element is always 1, this means
                            we return 1 only if there are no co-prime pairs.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
&F.bPiFNP.TtBQQ
```

**[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26F.bPiFNP.TtBQQ&input=%5B38%2C+70%2C+46%2C+98%2C+80%2C+105%2C+70%2C+78%2C+80%2C+46%2C+84%2C+116%2C+66%2C+81%2C+81%5D&debug=0)** or **[Check out Test Suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26F.bPiFNP.TtBQQ&input=%5B6%2C21%5D%0A%5B502%2C230%2C524%2C618%2C996%5D%0A%5B314%2C+112%2C938%2C+792%2C+309%5D%0A%5B666%2C+642%2C+658%2C+642%2C+849%2C+675%2C+910%2C+328%2C+320%5D%0A%5B922%2C+614%2C+530%2C+660%2C+438%2C+854%2C+861%2C+357%2C+477%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B6%2C21%5D%0A%5B502%2C230%2C524%2C618%2C996%5D%0A%5B314%2C+112%2C938%2C+792%2C+309%5D%0A%5B666%2C+642%2C+658%2C+642%2C+849%2C+675%2C+910%2C+328%2C+320%5D%0A%5B922%2C+614%2C+530%2C+660%2C+438%2C+854%2C+861%2C+357%2C+477%5D%0A%5B6%2C+7%5D%0A%5B629%2C+474%2C+502%2C+133%2C+138%5D%0A%5B420%2C+679%2C+719%2C+475%2C+624%5D%0A%5B515%2C+850%2C+726%2C+324%2C+764%2C+555%2C+752%2C+888%2C+467%5D%0A%5B946%2C+423%2C+427%2C+507%2C+899%2C+812%2C+786%2C+576%2C+844%5D&debug=0)**

This is a collaborative effort between [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) and [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder). Returns an inconsistent value (non-empty list) for truthy, and the empty list for falsy.

---

### ASCII-values

```
[38, 70, 46, 98, 80, 105, 70, 78, 80, 46, 84, 116, 66, 81, 81]
```

Which share the following factors:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 35, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 81]
```

---

## Explanation

```
&F.bPiFNP.TtBQQ
           tBQ   Return [Q, Q[1:]] (Q = eval first line of input)
         .T      Transpose ^ without cropping absences
        P        Remove last element of ^
  .b          Q  Map in parallel on ^ (N) and Q (Y, ignored)
     iFN           GCD of N
    P              Prime factors of ^ (P(1) = [])
&F               Left fold (reduce) the result of the map with Logical AND (short-circuiting)
```

---

Without the [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) requirement, this would've been a <s>7</s> 5-byte version accomplishing the same task (-2 thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman)):

```
-1iVt
```

---

## Explanation

```
-1iVtQQ  Implicit QQ at the end
    tQ   Return Q[1:]
  iV  Q  Vectorized GCD on ^ and Q
-1       Remove every element of ^ from [1] (implicit singleton)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the `Q`s at the end?

Comment: @ETHproductions Because `.b` has variable arities, and using implicit input means it will pick the lowest (1) instead of then intended (2).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `g`, 5 bytes

```
ϩĠ∑ȧv
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJnIiwiIiwiz6nEoOKIkcindiIsIiIsIlsyOCwxMzMsMTkwLDE0OCwxMThdIiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

I could save a byte with codepoint zero... Outputs 0 if falsy, any other number is truthy in vyxal